# get values from first column when other columns are true using a lookup list

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a **source** table with a variable number of columns. The first column is a **name**, and the remaining columns are **type** with values of `true` or `false` based on my data.

I also have an input **lookup** column that will have the names of the **types**.

Based on the **type**s selected in the **lookup** column, I want to return the **names** from the **source** column that has `true` for any of the selected **types**.

It is hard to explain so I made a sample sheet with expected output and explanation at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U7-Vz8tq-4E1Z6jkVFzsoIvW8VHRJNGw0oqDE1LUKOI/edit?usp=sharing has sample input and my expected output.

New rows could be added to the **source** table, and new columns (**types**) could be added too. One thought I was to have a formula for each row in the **source** table checking the column based on what is in the **lookup** table but I want to avoid that because new rows/columns could be added to the **source** table.

I'm hoping for a single `arrayformula` or something efficient. I have been looking at this for hours with no luck. I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **H9**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:F=TRUE, "♠"&B2:F2&"♦"&A3:A, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, G9:G)&"'"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

for **H3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:F=TRUE, "♠"&B2:F2&"♦"&A3:A, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, G3:G6)&"'"))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't end up using your exact formula but the use of `query` got me on the right track. I am doing it like this: look up column number of values in lookup list, use `CHAR` to convert that to a letter, joining the results so I end up with something like `A = TRUE OR C = TRUE`, and then using that with a `QUERY` call.