# Create column based on percentage of recurring customers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which contains order data, specified per row. So each row is a different order.

- date_created
- customer_id
- total_value
- recurring_customer

A customer is a recurring customer when they have ordered for the third time. I want to find out the percentage to which returning customers contribute to the total value.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_created" ["2019-11-16", "2019-11-16", "2019-11-16", "2019-11-16", "2019-11-16", "2019-11-16"]
        "customer_id": ["1733", "6356", "6457", "6599", "6637", "6638"],
        "total": ["746.02", "1236.60", "1002.32", "1187.21", "1745.03", "2313.14"],
        "recurring_customer": ["False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False"],
    }
)
```

By resampling the data to monthly data:

```py
df_monthly = df.resample('1M').mean()
```

I got the following output:

```py
df_monthly = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_created": ["2019-11-30", "2019-12-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-30"]
        "customer_id": ["4987.02", "5291.56", "5702.13", "6439.27", "7263.11", "8080.91",],
        "total": ["2915.25", "2550.85", "2486.72", "2515.81", "2633.77", "2558.19"],
        "recurring_customer": ["0.009050", "0.016667", "0.075630", "0.138122", "0.130045", "0.175503"],
    }
)
```

So, the real question is that I want to find out the percentage to which returning customers contribute to the total value of the month.

The desired output should look something like this:

```
| date_created | customer_id | total   | recurring_customer | recurring_customer_total | recurring_customer_total_percentage | 
| ------------ | ----------- | ------  | ------------------ | ------------------------ | ----------------------------------- |
|  2019-11-30  |  4987.02    | 2915.25 |       0.009050     |         ??????           |        ??????
|  2019-12-31  |  5291.56    | 2550.85 |       0.016667     |         ??????           |        ??????
|  2020-01-31  |  5702.13    | 2486.72 |       0.075630     |         ??????           |        ??????
|  2020-02-29  |  6439.27    | 2515.81 |       0.138122     |         ??????           |        ??????
|  2020-03-31  |  7263.11    | 2633.77 |       0.130045     |         ??????           |        ??????
|  2020-04-30  |  8080.91    | 2558.19 |       0.175503     |         ??????           |        ??????
```

Note that I can't just calculate the recurring_customer percentages times the total value because I assume the group of recurring customers contribute a lot more to the total value than customers who aren't a recurring customer.

I tried the np.where() function on the daily dataframe, where :

- I would create a column 'recurring_customer_total' in the daily dataframe and it would copy the value of the 'total' column but only when 'recurring_customer' return True, otherwise return 0. I found a similar question here: [get values from first column when other columns are true using a lookup list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049551/get-values-from-first-column-when-other-columns-are-true-using-a-lookup-list). Another similar question was asked here:
  [Getting indices of True values in a boolean list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448225/getting-indices-of-true-values-in-a-boolean-list).
  This answer returns all 'True' values and it's position, I want the
  value of 'total' copied into 'recurring_customer_total' when
  'recurring_customer' is 'True'.
- Then I would resample the daily dataframe to a monthly dataframe and that would give me the mean of the amount 'recurring_customers' contributed to the total value. Those values would be visible in 'recurring_customers_total'.
- The final step would be to calculate the percentage of the 'recurring_customer_total' based on the 'total' column. Those values should be stored in 'recurrings_customer_total_percentage'.

I think those are the steps I need to follow, the only problem is that I don't really know how to get there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I don't see any `datetime` column or index in `df`, so It's not possible to reproduce your steps.  What is the actual output of `df.head(6).to_dict()`?

Comment: Hi @laurent, I've added the date_created column (it's the index in datetime). Is it possible to reproduce now? I can show you the output of df.head(6).to_dict() if you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm fairly new to Python but I've managed to answer my own question. Can't say this is the best, easiest, fastest way but it surely helped.

First of all I made a new dataframe which is an exact copy of the original dataframe, but only with 'True' values of the column 'recurring_customer'. I did that by using the following code:

```
df_recurring_customers = df.loc[df['recurring_customer'] == True]
```

It gave me the following dataframe:

```
df_recurring_customers.head()
    {
        "date_created" ["2019-11-25", "2019-11-28", "2019-12-02", "2019-12-09", "2019-12-11"]
        "customer_id": ["577", "6457", "577", "6647", "840"],
        "total": ["33891.12", "81.98", "9937.68", "1166.28", "2969.60"],
        "recurring_customer": ["True", "True", "True", "True", "True"],
    }
)
```

Then I resampled the values using:

```
df_recurring_customers_monthly_sum = df_recurring_customers.resample('1M').sum()
```

I then dropped the 'number' and 'customer_id' column, which had no value. The next step was to join the two dataframes 'df_monthly' and 'df_recurring_customers_monthly_sum' using:

```
df_total = df_recurring_customers_monthly_sum.join(df_monthly)
```

This gave me:

```
| date_created | total      | recurring_customer_total |
| ------------ | ---------- | ------------------------ |
|  2019-11-30  | 644272.02  |         33973.10         |
|  2019-12-31  | 612205.99  |         15775.29         |
|  2020-01-31  | 887761.60  |         61612.27         |
|  2020-02-29  | 910724.75  |         125315.31        |
|  2020-03-31  | 1174662.59 |         125315.31        |
|  2020-04-30  | 1399332.26 |         248277.97        |
```

Then I wanted to know the percentage so

```
df_total['total_recurring_customer_percentage'] = (df_total['recurring_customer_total'] / df_total['total']) * 100
```

Which gave me:

```
| date_created | total      | recurring_customer_total | recurring_customer_total_percentage | 
| ------------ | ---------- | ------------------------ | ----------------------------------- |
|  2019-11-30  | 644272.02  |         33973.10         |        5.273099
|  2019-12-31  | 612205.99  |         15775.29         |        2.576794
|  2020-01-31  | 887761.60  |         61612.27         |        6.940182
|  2020-02-29  | 910724.75  |         125315.31        |        13.759954
|  2020-03-31  | 1174662.59 |         125315.31        |        13.967221
|  2020-04-30  | 1399332.26 |         248277.97        |        17.742603
```